# Saving cookies safely

Tags: qt, http, authentication, cookies, qt4

How can I safely store cookies between my program's sessions? Should I use encryption or is there another, simpler way? If I will use encryption, what is safer: store encrypted cookies in files or in registry (with QSettings)?

I use Qt.

Comment: What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: @SLaks user auth data. I use QWebView to allow user log in his web account (and then I get access token) instead of storing user's login and password and substitution them to login page fields.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase that.  **Who** are you trying to defend against?

Comment: @SLaks maybe malefactor. As good as I know if someone steal someone other's cookies he can easily get access to other's account. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to defend against people who can read the user's hard disk? If not, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @SLaks Oh, really, you're right. Maybe my 'mania of safety' is too big :) (Sorry for bad English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really needed to encrypt cookies when you save it to hard drive (if you aren't trying to defend against people who can read the user's hard disk).